# SignatureDoesNotMatch Error while downloading file using X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, amazon-s3

There are several questions related to this but this use case is slightlt different.

In Rails - In my controller I set response header explicitly :

```
   response.headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = "some_url"
```

Nginx Config

```
   location ~* ^/some_url/(.*){     

            set $s3_bucket        '$arg_bucket_name';
            set $aws_access_key   'AWSAccessKeyId=$arg_AWSAccessKeyId';
            set $url_expires      'Expires=$arg_Expires';
            set $url_signature    'Signature=$arg_Signature';
            set $url_full         '$1?$aws_access_key&$url_expires&$url_signature';
            proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
            add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename=$arg_filename';
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
            proxy_buffering        off;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            resolver               4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
            proxy_pass             https://$s3_bucket/$url_full;
}
```

Using this to download 100 of files through nginx ,in few cases I am getting error

```
          SignatureDoesNotMatch

          The request signature we calculated does not match with the signature you provide.
```

Comment: Do any of these URLs have unusual characters in them,  such as non-alphanumeric ASCII-equivalent single-byte symbols such as `+` or `*`? Or any multibyte?  Is the behavior repeatable with the same URL?  Can you edit to add the full output error XML? Despite appearances, the Signature Does Not Match error XML does not contain any sensitive data other than your access-key-id, which is not technically considered sensitive, either (only the secret key is) but you can remove that if desired.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  .. yes i have  +  in my Signature . ..Signature is 6l6B0ZiXt5yJskENVJWGGCWPV+Q=  How I can resolve this?

Comment: Replace each `+` with `%2B`.  Don't laugh.